# Can't use += in c#?

Tags: c#

My class has just switched to c# from java so I am still learning its syntax. It might sound a stupid question, but im stuck for an hour now without answer to a simple question, is there += in c#?

```
for (int i = 0; i < users.Count(); i++) {
            double sum += users[i].getFine();
```

it gives me and error at sum += part saying:

> "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object
>   expressions can be used as a statement"

Comment: Define you sum before your loop and use it as `sum += users[i].getFine();`.

Comment: You are declaring the variable in each loop and you cannot sum. Probably you want to move out the declaration out of the for loop (`double sum = 0;`) and inside the loop just do the addition (`sum += users[i].getFine();`).

Comment: Try reading "C# in a nutshell", it's a well explained book about all aspects of the C# language (And some CLR)

Comment: That's probably not any different from Java. It just makes no sense to declare and increment a variable at the same time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should first define your variable and then try to alter it using +=

```
double sum=0;
for (int i = 0; i < users.Count(); i++) 
    sum += users[i].getFine();
```

`sum += x;` equals to `sum = sum + x ;`

You can learn more of it at [MSDN += Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx)

I hope this simple answer turns out to be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

It is working  as it should be.

This:

```
 double sum += users[i].getFine();
```

is equal to

```
double sum =  sum + users[i].getFine();
```

And `sum` does not exist at the moment you try to add it to `users[i].getFine`.
The error you are getting means, that compiler has no idea about what you are trying to do - you should assing something to a variable, or increment other, or await something, or do any of other things in this message.

Also, this code would not work as expected anyway, as it is being rewritten at every loop. The `sum` should be defined outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think your posted code would do as below. Essentially on every loop iteration you are declaring a new variable `double sum` and in such case the code `sum += users[i].getFine();` does it make sense at all. NO, it's meaning less and logic less. Thus compiler throwing the error asking you to declare the variable `sum` out of loop scope.

```
for (int i = 0; i < users.Count(); i++) {
            double sum += users[i].getFine();
```